# How do I determine if a sequence contains the values of another sequence?

Tags: freemarker

I have two sequences of integers. I want to determine if the sequence A contains a values of seuqence B, and then get the values of B that are inside A.

This is what I tried:

```
<#assign myArticles = [50901,50369] />
<#assign articles = [50369, 50379, 50901] />

<#list myArticles as article>
    ${articles?seq_contains(article)?string("yes", "no")}
</#list>
```

And it works (result "yes"), but when I use a List it doesn't work (result "no"):

```
<#assign articlesList = articleService.getArticles(groupId) />
<#assign articlesArray = [50901,50369] />

<#assign articlesId = []>
<#list articlesList as item>
    <#assign articlesId = articlesId + [item.getArticleId()]>
    <#-- articlesId gives me this ids: 50369, 50379, 50901 -->
</#list>

<#list articlesArray as article>
    ${articlesId?seq_contains(article)?string("yes", "no")}
</#list>
```

Why?

Comment: I don't spot any problems in the FTL itself... One possibility is that the return value of `item.getArticleId()` is a `String` that looks like a number when printed. Then it isn't equivalent with the number that looks the same.

Comment: @ddekany thank you so much!! that was the problem.. I converted `item.getArticleId()?number` to number and it works.

Comment: Perhaps there's a reason that it's a `String` (it can sometimes contain letters or something), in which case it's safer to convert the number to string via `?c` instead.